# Does a website automatically become responsive by adding Bootstrap CDN?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I was told that Bootstrap is responsible by itself. So does a custom-made webpage, using Bootstrap become automatically responsive ? Or do we have to specify responsive instructions. If I add the Bootstrap CDN and implement the built-in components, will it automatically be responsive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you are using a responsive framework such as **Bootstrap**,and implementing its components, then you'll have a **responsive website**.

But most important, in every html page, you'll need to add this below viewport code as well. inside `HEAD` Tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You can read more about viewports on this [mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Thank you. I needed this information to start with my first-ever project. Much appreciated.

Comment: good ! best of luck ahead, we are always here to help on **Stack Overflow** ! shoot your questions, no matter how silly they seem to be :)